# Displaying an image in a row of a Xpages mobile dataview

Tags: mobile, xpages

Is it possible to display an icon or image in a row of a dataview when using the XPages UP1 mobile control?
A facet for an icon is available in the control but it does not seem to render an image/icon on the browser page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iconColumn does render on mobile controls using Domino 9.0

Answer (score 1):

Icons can be displayed in **DataView** on mobile.

On **DataView** control there is a property **iconColumn -> icons**.
It can be done like so:

```
<xe:this.iconColumn>
  <xe:viewIconColumn>
    <xe:this.icons>
      <xe:iconEntry alt="Discussion" styleClass="mblListItemIcon">
          <xp:this.url>.....
```

For a complete example, please look at the code in **TeamRoom** template in **dynamicMobileView.xsp** Custom Control.

Answer (score 0):

The DataView automatically renders in mobile using a different renderer. If I remember correctly it uses divs instead of a table. I don't think the icon column is included in that renderer. Safari allows you to switch user agents to see mobile render and I'm pretty sure there are Firefox adding for that too.

Comment: Yes it uses divs, and the renderer is not rendering the column although it does emit a class something...noicon.